# Not entering Function

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script to remotely rename multiple computers. Here's what I have (I know the Verify function works so that can be skipped over. The issue is occurring with the GetComputers function)

```
function main{
    $DomainCredential = Verify
    $computers = GetComputers
    #Rename -computers $computers -DomainCredential $DomainCredential
}
function Verify{
    # Prompt for Credentials and verify them using the DirectoryServices.AccountManagement assembly.
    Write-Host "Please provide your credentials so the script can continue."
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
    # Extract the current user's domain and also pre-format the user name to be used in the credential prompt.
    $UserDomain = $env:USERDOMAIN
    $UserName = "$UserDomain\$env:USERNAME"
    # Define the starting number (always #1) and the desired maximum number of attempts, and the initial credential prompt message to use.
    $Attempt = 1
    $MaxAttempts = 5
    $CredentialPrompt = "Enter your Domain account password (attempt #$Attempt out of $MaxAttempts):"
    # Set ValidAccount to false so it can be used to exit the loop when a valid account is found (and the value is changed to $True).
    $ValidAccount = $False
    # Loop through prompting for and validating credentials, until the credentials are confirmed, or the maximum number of attempts is reached.
    Do {
        # Blank any previous failure messages and then prompt for credentials with the custom message and the pre-populated domain\user name.
        $FailureMessage = $Null
        $Credentials = Get-Credential -UserName $UserName -Message $CredentialPrompt
        # Verify the credentials prompt wasn't bypassed.
        If ($Credentials) {
            # If the user name was changed, then switch to using it for this and future credential prompt validations.
            If ($Credentials.UserName -ne $UserName) {
                $UserName = $Credentials.UserName
            }
            # Test the user name (even if it was changed in the credential prompt) and password.
            $ContextType = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
            Try {
                $PrincipalContext = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext $ContextType,$UserDomain
            } Catch {
                If ($_.Exception.InnerException -like "*The server could not be contacted*") {
                    $FailureMessage = "Could not contact a server for the specified domain on attempt #$Attempt out of $MaxAttempts."
                } Else {
                    $FailureMessage = "Unpredicted failure: `"$($_.Exception.Message)`" on attempt #$Attempt out of $MaxAttempts."
                }
            }
            # If there wasn't a failure talking to the domain test the validation of the credentials, and if it fails record a failure message.
            If (-not($FailureMessage)) {
                $ValidAccount = $PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials($UserName,$Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
                If (-not($ValidAccount)) {
                    $FailureMessage = "Bad user name or password used on credential prompt attempt #$Attempt out of $MaxAttempts."
                }
            }
        # Otherwise the credential prompt was (most likely accidentally) bypassed so record a failure message.
        } Else {
            $FailureMessage = "Credential prompt closed/skipped on attempt #$Attempt out of $MaxAttempts."
        }

        # If there was a failure message recorded above, display it, and update credential prompt message.
        If ($FailureMessage) {
            Write-Warning "$FailureMessage"
            $Attempt++
            If ($Attempt -lt $MaxAttempts) {
                $CredentialPrompt = "Authentication error. Please try again (attempt #$Attempt out of $MaxAttempts):"
            } ElseIf ($Attempt -eq $MaxAttempts) {
                $CredentialPrompt = "Authentication error. THIS IS YOUR LAST CHANCE (attempt #$Attempt out of $MaxAttempts):"
            }
        }
    } Until (($ValidAccount) -or ($Attempt -gt $MaxAttempts))
    # If the credentials weren't successfully verified, then exit the script.
    If (-not($ValidAccount)) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "You failed $MaxAttempts attempts at providing a valid user credentials. Exiting the script now... "
        EXIT
    } Else {
        Write-Host "Credntials authenticated"
        return $Credentials
    }
}
function GetComputers{
    $oldnames = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    Write-Output "Enter the PC numbers to be named. Do not include 'PC' only type the following numbers. Type 'end' when finished"
    $userinput = Read-Host
    while($userinput -ne "end"){
        $userinput = "$('PC')$($userinput)"
        [void]$oldnames.Add($userinput)
        $userinput = Read-Host
        }
    return $oldnames
}

workflow Rename($computers, $DomainCredential){
    foreach -parallel ($computer in $computers){
        $newname = "$($computer)$('MK')"
        Rename-Computer -PSComputerName $computer -NewName $newname -DomainCredential $DomainCredential
    }
}

main
```

The Verify function works perfectly, but then it just hangs and nothing else happens. I added a debug line between the call of the Verify and the call of the GetComputer functions, and that also printed out. Im new to powershell and am out of ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain that it is hanging, or is `Read-Host` just showing a blank input location? Calling that function without any arguments will just give you a blinking cursor in command line. Try adding some form of prompt to read-host, like below:

```
PS C:\Users\mbolton> $var=read-host
"string"

PS C:\Users\mbolton> $var
"string"

PS C:\Users\mbolton> $var=read-host "type something in"
type something in: "different string"

PS C:\Users\mbolton> $var
"different string"

PS C:\Users\mbolton>
```